# Why are my object values not available outside of my AJAX callback function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, object, parameter-passing

I am extracting data from a game on facebook and storing those values in an object, which is then passed to a PHP page. Everything works except for the fact that the values stored in the object are somehow not being assigned to the global object variable.

If I print out the values of each key within the function, everything is fine. However, if I print them outside of the function, they return null, except for key values that were assigned outside of the function.

```
var myObj={};
var key, val, i, nxtCell;
var srcStrings=["Attack","Defense","Health","Energy","Stamina"];

$.ajax(
{
type:'GET',url:'<game link'+uID,
dataType:'html',
success:function(data)
{
    var table=$(data);
    var myTD=table.find("td");

    $(myTD).each(function()
    {


        for(i=0;srcStrings.length>i;i++)
        {
            if($(this).text().indexOf(srcStrings[i])>=0 && $(this).text().indexOf("by")<0)
            {

                key=$.trim($(this).text());
                key=key.replace(':','');
                val=$.trim($(this).closest("td").next().text());                
                myObj[key]=val;




            }
        };
    });

            // This print works fine.
    $.each(myObj, function(key, value)
    {
        console.log(key + ":" + value);
    });

}
});

// Printing myObj key -> value pairs does not work here.
```

As I said, the last each function prints out the object values. But they won't print out outside of the AJAX callback. I tried passing data to a function outside of the AJAX call to see if that had any effect, and it did not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because when you try and print the values outside of your AJAX callback function, `myObj` is still just an empty Object (besides any keys/values you set for it explicitly).

E.G.

```
var myObj = {};
$.ajax({
  // Settings and callback function that manipulates myObj
})

// Code to print myObj Key -> Value pairs
```

All of this code is run serially, and since your AJAX call has not returned by the time you are printing `myObj`, it doesn't have the values that you are expecting.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have a Post that occurs right after the code listed above. Those values aren't posting, because of this reason. Could you tell me what the work around would be please?